# Ignore first set of parentheses in split

Tags: python

I have been using the code below to strip out text before a space and opening parenthesis. The strings originally were in this format:

```
abc def ghij (xyz)(1-1)
```

So this line worked fine:

```
dataStrip.split(" (", 1)[0]
```

The syntax has now changed so that sometimes additional parentheses appear earlier in the string:

```
abc (def) ghij (xyz)(1-1)
```

Is there a straightforward way of ignoring the first set of parentheses in the split to give the following result?

```
abc (def) ghij
```

Comment: The problem is that you say that "_sometimes_ additional parentheses appear earlier in the string". How should an algorithm find out if this is one of the sometimes?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that there are two sets of `(stuff)` after the text you want to extract?

Comment: The big question is, do you want to *ignore* the first set, or *keep* the next-to-last set?

Comment: As an aside, if you have any control or influence over what the input should look like, I'd argue for something that's much easier to parse.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your two different cases, `dataSplit.rsplit(" (", 1)[0]` will do the trick: